# Difference between Singleton and SRP(Single Responsibility Principle)

Tags: oop, design-patterns

**Difference between Singleton and SRP(Single Responsibility Principle)**
Can you explain the difference in plain language with examples?

Comment: What's wrong with plain language explanation at wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object is a person,  singleton means that there is only one person of a given type in the world. You cannot find there are another person of the same type in the world.

Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) means that a person only focus on and can only do one thing. So even if you are the only the person of a given type in the world (i.e. singleton) , if you can do many things that are not related to each other , you are not SRP enough.

So you can see they are different concepts which do not related to each other. Singleton is about the quantity of certain kind of object. SRP is about what things can an object do.

Comment: That is, the SRP class can have more than one object?

Comment: yes. it is controlled by you . If you want it to have only one object , it is singleton. Otherwise , it is not singleton